# Scraping Web Pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I have some page where the pagination is dynamicaly generated, the URL is visible when I use inspection tool from Chrome or Firefox, but the href="#" when I visualize the source code or when I use xpath via scrapy.

any hint about this issue?

webpage: http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/paris-75/restaurants
link: "suivant" at the footer, class="link_pagination next"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the quuickest approach for you will be generating that link by simply adding the parameter page to the request and iterating along all pages (if thats what you want), in this case for example will be:

```
http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/paris-75/restaurants?page=2
http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/paris-75/restaurants?page=3
...
...
http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/paris-75/restaurants?page=644
http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/paris-75/restaurants?page=645
```

Good luck with it! ;)